# how to change the position of picker view after changing the orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

I am having two buttons with picker view in my app. When in portrait mode these buttons are placed on the left side, as I change the orientation of the device to landscape the buttons shift to the right side of screen, but  picker view remains at left side only. I need the picker to change its position and move to the right side.

Any idea on how this can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

make an object of your pickerView. Set @property and @synthesixe for it. Make connections in your .xib ! And then write the following code in your viewDidLoad() !

```
pickerViewObject.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

if you want to add more than one autoresizing mask then use | operator. !!

```
pickerViewObject.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: you can also set the autoresizing mask through .xib ! First unCheck the autoLayout option and then goto utilities --->> inspector and there you can set autosizing mask ! alternatively you can disable all autosizing mask in your .xib and then do it through code as shown above !

Answer (score 1):

I have done following changes in my code and i am getting required result....

```
-(void) didReceivedRotaionChanged
{
    if([popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        if ([popoverController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        {
            UINavigationController * navController = (UINavigationController*)popoverController.contentViewController;
            NSArray *array = navController.viewControllers;
            if ([array count] > 0)
            {
                if([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self.nsJobRolePickerViewController])
               {
                    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
                    [self onClickIJobRoleButton:self.btnJobRole];

                }
                else if([[array objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self.nsLocationPickerViewController])
                {
                    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
                    [self onClickILocationButton:self.btnLocation];

                }
            .
            .
            ......
```

etc..

Well it's bit lengthy... but it will help those who are beginners like me..

Answer (score 0):

you have to unCheck the "AutoLayout" option available in Utilities -> File Inspector in your .xib !!

Comment: "AutoLayout" is unchecked but still it's not giving proper output.